# Отмена асинхронных параллельных операций c#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, асинхронность

Есть список задач (вызов одного и того же метода), происходит примерно так:

```
//цикл, содержащий код: 
async Task<Result> function() await _pushData(data, cToken);
_taskList.Add(Task.Run(function, cToken));
```

После цикла:

```
await Task.WhenAll(_taskList);
```

`_pushData` внутри содержит очень много подзадач, практически каждая из которых вызывает `cToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` при старте. Некоторые (большие) - несколько раз, перед каждой сложной операцией. Сами задачи обрабатывают разное количество данных.

Вызывающий данный цикл код содержит следующее:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    await PushDataThere(data, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

    _log.Info("Успешно.");
}
catch (PushCancelledException ex)
{
    cts.Cancel();
    _log.Fatal("Остановка задач.");
    throw;
}
```

Здесь я ловлю исключение, если таковое имеется - отменяю сразу все задачи.

Суть проблемы в том, что я написал тестовый выброс исключения в методе `_pushData`, и во всех 44 глобальных задачах всегда вызывается `throw new Exception("Test");` еще до вызова `cts.Cancel();`. Т.е. мне нужно выбросить исключение, если таковое возникло, **до** завершения всех задач.

Можно ли как-то с этим бороться?

Comment: Ваш `await Task.WhenAll(_taskList);` должен упасть на этих исключениях, максимально быстро, судя по описанию. Этого не происходит?

Comment: @Monk, нет. Сначала заканчиваются все задачи, потом только исключение выбрасывается из `WhenAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899842/how-to-cancel-and-raise-an-exception-on-task-whenall-if-any-exception-is-raised).

Т.е. ко всем параллельным задачам (верхнего уровня) нужно вызвать `ContinueWith(task => cts.Cancel(), cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);`. Тогда, будет вызван коллбэк `task => cts.Cancel()` в случае исключения в задаче, и отмена произойдет раньше чем вернется управление из `WhenAll(tasks)`.

В моем коде, мне пришлось в `_pushData` передать не `CancellationToken` а `CancellationTokenSource`.